# Appending svg element to a DOM element doesn't show

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I used this code to generate and append an svg element a DOM element.

```
var svg_el = document.createElement("svg");
svg_el.className = "symbol";
var use_el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
use_el.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', '#my-symbol-icon');
// use_el.setAttribute('href', '#exp-col-icon');      // tried also this
svg_el.appendChild(use_el)

var element = document.getElementById("myElement");
element.appendChild(svg_el)
```

This is how I see my svg element when I inspect my web page, however it's not visually there.

```
<div id="myElement"><svg class="symbol"><use xlink:href="#my-symbol-icon"></use></svg></div>
```

If I add the same exact code manually, it works visually as expected, but I need to make it work with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

This made svg element be shown with no problems.

```
var svg_el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
svg_el.setAttribute('class',"symbol");
var use_el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
use_el.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', '#my-symbol-icon');

var element = document.getElementById("myElement");
element.appendChild(svg_el)
```

I don't know exactly why this works, while the code in question seems that it should work.